# align Buttons in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, android-layout

I am  trying to align buttons like simple calculator
But when i align buttons like that when i run it buttons can shift from desired location.
I can't understand what is problem.

[image]
[image]

Here is the  Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >





<Button
android:id="@+id/zero"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
android:text="zero" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/dot"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zero"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/equ"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zero"
android:text="dot" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/zero"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zero"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:layout_centerInParent="false"
android:layout_centerVertical="false"
android:text="one" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button01"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:layout_centerInParent="false"
android:layout_centerVertical="false"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
android:text="two" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button2"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_above="@+id/zero"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zero"
 android:text="three" />
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/equ"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dot"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
 android:layout_below="@+id/Button04"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
 android:text="equal" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button02"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"
android:text="four" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button03"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button02"
android:text="five" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button04"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/equ"
android:text="six" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button05"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/Button02"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button03"
android:text="seven" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button06"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/Button03"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button04"
android:text="eight" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button07"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button06"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button06"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/equ"
android:text="nine" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/pls"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button04"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/equ"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button05"
android:text="pls" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/sub"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/Button07"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button07"
android:text="sub" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/mul"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sub"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sub"
android:text="mul" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/neg"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mul"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mul"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mul"
android:text="neg" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button11"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/neg"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/neg"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button05"
android:text="div" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/neg"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button11"
android:text="@string/mkcalcolate"
tools:context=".Mksoft" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

its just a simple align but it's not working

Comment: Looks like its working.  It just isn't doing what you expect.  Look at your alignment for Button05 for example.  Why is it aligned on Button03?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put all Buttons first, then i set all id's and other stuff that was my wrong. 
when you use many Buttons you must set id's one by one and align it.